# elasticsearch-curator for elasticsearch-v7.2.0

Tags: kubernetes-helm, elasticsearch-curator

I am trying to run elasticsearch curator on kubernetes using  helm install stable/elasticsearch-curator but pctestcontainerregistry.azurecr.io/eic-curator:5.5.4 is not compatible with elasticsearch-v7.2.0. Refer error below. Does anyone has any alternate of running es-curator on kubernetes for elasticsearch-v7.2.0?

```
2019-08-12 21:14:05,422 INFO      Preparing Action ID: 1, "delete_indices"
2019-08-12 21:14:05,433 ERROR     Elasticsearch version 7.2.0 incompatible with this version of Curator (5.5.4)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/curator/utils.py", line 900, in get_client
    check_version(client)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/curator/utils.py", line 701, in check_version
    '({1})'.format(".".join(map(str,version_number)), __version__)
curator.exceptions.CuratorException: Elasticsearch version 7.2.0 incompatible with this version of Curator (5.5.4)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/curator", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 722, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 697, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 895, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 535, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/curator/cli.py", line 213, in cli
    run(config, action_file, dry_run)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/curator/cli.py", line 160, in run
    client = get_client(**client_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/curator/utils.py", line 907, in get_client
    'Error: {0}'.format(e)
elasticsearch.exceptions.ElasticsearchException: Unable to create client connection to Elasticsearch.  Error: Elasticsearch version 7.2.0 incompatible with this version of Curator (5.5.4)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Curator version 5.7.6 works with all Elasticsearch 7.x series. You will just have to update the helm chart and/or image to use it.

Comment: Thanks .. i used repository: untergeek/curator and tag: 5.7.6 and it worked out for me.